# Make a div container between two columns

Tags: css, html

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/BxQ8n/2/`

```
body
{
    background:url('http://i42.tinypic.com/2e5pbbc.jpg');
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
}

div.container
{
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
}

div.container img#logo
{
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    height: 200px;
    width: 800px;
}

div.container div.top20
{
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}

div.container div.menu
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 796px;
}

div.container div#login
{
    border: 1px solid orange;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}

div.container div#search
{
    border: 1px solid purple;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}

input
{
    width: 180px; margin: 0.5em 0 0 0.55em;
}

input.btn
{
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0.4em;
    width: 190px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #555555;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.container div#other
{
    border: 1px solid cyan;
    width: 200px;
    height: 570px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

Here is the full screen result http://jsfiddle.net/BxQ8n/2/embedded/result/

What I want need is:

1. create another div that will be between my two columns
2. Eliminate the space between logo and menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the logo to display properly, wrap the image in a div and set a definite height.
For a 3 column layout, you will need to create 3 divs, div1, div2 and div3. All these divs will require float:left with widths that will add up to the container width.

Here's the fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zqhb/4/

```
#left{
 float: left;
 width: 200px;   
}

#middle{
 float: left;
 width: 400px;
}

#right{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

It's not clean and semantic by any means but you get the point i think.

Comment: Thank you it works...You could also remove `float` and `clear` from other div and write `float: right` instead of left in the `#right` and its works same good. Logo fixed too.

Answer (score 1):

Puts them in there own container so something like this

```
<div id="Containerleft">
  <div id="top 20 songs"></div>
  <div id="top 20 artists"></div>
</div>
<div id="Containermiddle">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="Containerright">
  <div id="login"></div>
  <div id="other"></div>
</div>
```

Float all to the left and this should solve your problem 
This also set the width to fit the main container so if your main container was 100 make your left container 20, middle 60 and right 20 pixels.

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you `float:left` your div's, it is in my opinion the easiest way to build up a website.
After that you can give your div's a different `Height` & `Width`.

```
<div id="Containter">
    <div id="LeftPart">
      <div id="T20Songs">top 20 songs</div>
      <div id="T20Artists">top 20 artists</div>
    </div>
    <div id="MiddlePart">
      <div id="MainContent">MainContent</div>
    </div>
    <div id="RightPart">
      <div id="Login">Login</div>
      <div id="Other">Other</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
    Containter {
     width:900px;
    }
    LeftPart {
     float:left;
     width:200px;
    }

    MiddlePart {
     float:left;
     width:500px
    }

    RightPart {
     float:left;
     width:200px;
    }
```

Pay attention to the Width & Height of your main container